# Difference between "%~dp0" and ".\"?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Let's say I'm using a batch file and want it to direct to a folder located in the same directory of the batch. If I'm not wrong you would write "%~dp0\whateverfoldername". But can't the same done by just writing ".\whateverfoldername"? If so, what is the difference and/or advantage of the respective command?

Comment: Maybe you can.  But that will fail miserably if the current directory is not where you hope it is.

Comment: Which would result from running as admin... thus you do what RGuggisberg below says.. i get it now lol

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
pushd %~dp0
```

is often used to change to the original directory from which the batch was started.
This is very useful in newer OS's when the user may 'Run as administrator' which changes the current directory for you!  Try it sometime.  Just make a simple bat

```
@echo off
echo.CD=%CD%
pushd %~dp0
echo.CD=%CD%
pause
```

Now run it.
Now run it again 'As Administrator' on Vista, Win 7, Win 8, 2008 Server, or 2012 Server.
See what happens?

Comment: Ok this helps a lot, i see why dp0 is needed. But what is the difference between pushd and cd?

Comment: Answering myself: Difference between pushd and cd is that pushd stores the previous folder/path for use by the POPD command. POPD Changes directory back to the path/folder most recently stored by the PUSHD command. Boom. I love you guys thanks!

Comment: If you need to traverse the root to another drive, PUSHD works seamlessly whereas with CD you would need to either use CD with the /d parameter or call CD and then type the drive name.

Comment: I think we can always use PUSHD instead of CD. For that in my custom shell I replace CD with PUSHD with the following command: 'doskey cd=pushd $*' Now you can do something like 'cd C:\win*\sy*32' and then 'popd' to go back.

Answer (score 3):

`".\` will locate with respect to the `CURRENT` directory, hence if you have changed directories with a `CD` command then you will be looking at `THAT` directory, not the directory in which the batch resides.

In fact, it's normal to create a separate directory, often called `\batch` or perhaps `\belfry` to keep batch files. Provided the `,bat` in question is locared on the `path`, it will be located. `%dp0` will yield the location of the `.bat`.

Comment: Also, the working directory may differ from the parent directory of the script depending on how the script was launched.