# Running a batch file through command prompt - system cannot find the path specified

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to uninstall Oracle on this Windows 7 (64 bit) machine by downloading a standalone tool from Oracle, I need to run a batch file that is supposed to uninstall but I am unable to run it.

I tried to open command prompt as administrator and I am trying to run this as below: 
[image]

As you can clearly see from the screenshot, I am doing a "dir" on the directory and can clearly see the file right there. Not sure what's going on here.

I also tried to run the batch file by double clicking from Windows Explorer and a terminal window opens and closes quickly but the batch file is not doing what it is supposed to do (it is clearly not executing from Windows Explorer).

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I also tried using the full path like "c:\temp\deinstall.bat" but same results.

Comment: Open the bat file in notepad. I'll bet it starts with `@echo off`, and that the error is actually coming from inside the batch file. The error if the batch file itself wasn't found is `'X' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Thanks. Just turned echo off and found out that the system was not complaining about the deinstall.bat but another file referenced within the script. Thanks! That resolved my problem.

Answer (score 13):

As theB pointed out above in a comment, this worked for me:

> Open the bat file in notepad. I'll bet it starts with @echo off, and
>   that the error is actually coming from inside the batch file. The
>   error if the batch file itself wasn't found is 'X' is not recognized
>   as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Answer (score 3):

'Run as Administrator' changes the current directory. See my answer here
[Difference between "%~dp0" and ".\"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890856/difference-between-dp0-and/15891127#15891127)