# Why working directory changes to system32 when executing a batch file that's in a different directory and how to change it

Tags: batch-file, windows-task-scheduler, system32

I have a batch file that's in my desktop and it works properly when I execute it using double click. But when I execute it using a task scheduler or run as administrator, the working directory changes to C:\Windows\system32 and it doesn't work properly.

What's the reason why it happens and how do I retain the working directory?

Comment: The solution is simple. You should specify the working directory in your script, and/or use absolute file paths. You can specify the current working directory using the `CD` command, or the `PushD` command.

Comment: I've tried using the %cd% variable to get the current working directory, but it still returns the directory for system32

Comment: `%CD%` tells you what the current directory is, but I'm talking about the `CD` command! If you wanted the working directory to be that of the script itself, then your first line should be either ```@CD /D "%~dp0."```, or ```@PushD "%~dp0."```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this line at the top of your bat file:

```
pushd %~dp0
```

See this post for details
[Difference between "%~dp0" and ".\"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890856/difference-between-dp0-and/15891127#15891127)

Comment: `pushd %~dp0` does not work if the batch file is in a directory like `C:\Temp\Development & Test(!) 100%`. The working solution is `pushd "%~dp0" || exit /B` and of course the batch file should use `popd` before exiting. It would be also good to make sure that the command extensions are enabled with using `setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion` below `@echo off` in batch file before `pushd` command line as otherwise the command `pushd` could fail on batch file started using a UNC path and command extensions are not enabled by chance (very unlikely, but not impossible).