# MSI installer does not install when executed from a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line, command-line-interface, windows-installer

I am currently creating an improvised installer for a cople software packages. To do this I have to install a couple MSI packages first before doing a couple file operations.

To install an MSI package I am using the following command:

```
start /wait msiexec /i "Myinstaller V2.1.msi" /qb
```

This command works and installs the package instantly and witout any problems via CMD.

But when I put this command in my batch file and execute it as an administrator, I get the following error:
`This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package`

What cold be the problem? Using the same command via the console works flawlessly, only the batch file throws the error...

**EDIT:** I have also tried the `/a` parameter in order to install it as an administrator and it does not work either. Full command in batch file:

```
start /wait msiexec /qn /a "Myinstaller V2.1.msi"
```

**EDIT2:** I just realized that it only **does not work** when I start the batch file with `Right click > Run as administrator`
When I open a console with administrative rights and start my batch file it works for some reason...

Is there a way to make it work with the `Right click > Run as administrator` method?

**SOLUTION:** Thanks to RGuggisberg's answer I now know that the [directory changes once the file is executed as an administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890856/difference-between-dp0-and/15891127#15891127). With a small change the installer gets fired up as an admin and works perfectly starting the installer from a relative path in the same directory:

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
start /wait msiexec /i "Myinstaller V2.1.msi" /qb
pause
```

I've now also implemented a feature to detect wether or not the installation fails or not:

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
start /wait msiexec /i "Myinstaller V2.1.msi" /qb
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo SUCCESSFULL 
if NOT %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo MyProgram installation FAILED
pause
```

Answer (score 2):

The current directory changes when you run as administrator. If you want to prove that to yourself, see this post
[Difference between "%~dp0" and ".\"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890856/difference-between-dp0-and/15891127#15891127)
Include the full path to your filename and it will work.